# I've got some error in uploading array of array files in Postman

Tags: node.js, postman

How can I upload an array of array file using Postman.

Ex. `[ [array of files], [array of files] ]`

I've got some error when I try

`file[]` -> value is 3 files
`file[]` -> value is 2 files

[image]

Comment: what kind of error did you get? Please add this to your question.

Comment: I use this multer code 

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null,  Date.now() + ".png") 
  }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).array("media")

I try to upload two files using media[0] and 1 file in media[1] using Postman.

The error I received is MulterError: Unexpected field